# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getUserMedia' of undefined on mobile devices using local IP using React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, webrtc

I am experiencing an odd error, I am currently creating a React Video Chat Application utilizing WebRTC and what I find odd is that when I go to my Localhost where react is hosted everything seems to work fine, but when I try to view the react web app on my phone using my local ip and the same port I get this error,
[image]

I get the same error as well when I use my local ip on my desktop browser and not local host.

Here is my code for the function that is causing issues. I also have a back end with Node Js as well for this project, so could it be that its because my site is not officially deployed?

Function in question:

```
useEffect(() => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
        .then((currentStream)=> {
            setStream(currentStream);

            myVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;
        });

    socket.on('me', (id) => setMe(id)); 

    socket.on('calluser', ({ from, name: callerName, signal}) => {
        setCall({isReceivedCall: true, from, name: callerName, signal});
    });
}, []);
```

Comment: As per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia - Note: If the current document isn't loaded securely, navigator.mediaDevices will be undefined, and you cannot use getUserMedia(). See Security for more information on this and other security issues related to using getUserMedia().

Comment: Oh okay that makes a lot more sense, I believe it should work once its deployed because it will be secured with 'https'